# Raspberry requests the wrong SSL certificate

Tags: raspbian

I have a little website on altervista.org. I use my raspberry to do regularly calls to this website. Since some days I get an certificate expiration error. Opening the website in a browser on a laptop works flawlessly.
Further investigation reveals that running `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect felixfeneon.altervista.org:443` on my laptop requests the correct and valid certificate, while running the identical command on the raspberry retrieves a certificate from someothersite.altervista.org, expired on 09-30. How can that be?

Rasperry Pi 2, runnning Raspbian wheezy.

Comment: *runnning Raspbian wheezy* ... really? wheezy? as a matter of interest - what is the result of `openssl version`

Comment: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016 ... ok, that is quite old. Would a current raspian run on a Pi 2? (headless). I tried upgrading, but that went wrong; i had to restore a backup. I fear installing a new version.

Comment: current Raspberry Pi OS runs on **all** pi's - upgrading major versions has never been "supported" by the Raspberry Pi organisation, however, my main Pi started out on wheezy and I've successfully upgraded to Buster - note: didn't upgrade from Wheezy directly to Buster - upgraded each major version when it was released - which would be the only possible way to succeed. i.e. wheezy -> jessie -> stretch -> buster